# How to prepare channel images for CNN training?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm training a six-channel image for cell segmentation which is separate. The six images depicted down there are the same but in different channels.

[image: six channels]

How should I arrange the array for input to my network? Put it all together in array with numpy.dstack? Or directly in the layers? I know that we should be attentive to the filters numbers and size too, it's to be treated like an RGB image but I'm new in Deep Learning and computer vision and I got this question bugging me.

I'm using Python for image editing (PIL and OpenCV) and TensorFlow with Keras for image processing.

The shape of the images after crop around the cells is 30x30 each in an array each channel.

[image]

Comment: For training with keras, you can not have images with more than 4 channels (rgba) so you need to right a custom data generator and use array of arrays instead of image. Search about the custom data generators and you will find the way.

Answer (score 2):

My advise is

Like with most Deep learning questions the answer is to try it out. Have the inputs be of shape `(batch_size, 30, 30, 6)` with np.dstack and train a model. I assume you will be using `Conv2D` so the channel combinations shouldn't matter.

However if you are planning to use transfer learning ([pretrained_models](https://keras.io/applications/)) you might need to drop channel or `sum` them together to get shape `(batch_size, 30, 30, 3)` since most of those models are expecting 3 channels

Comment: ksooklall - I didn't get the second part of your explanation, I'll give it a try with transfer learning too, but I fail to see why would I need to drop a channel or sum 'em. What do you mean by summing the channels?

Comment: oh i mean't a lot of pretrained models use 3 channels, like Resnet, VGG so on

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use the transfer learning, then the default image size should be (224, 224) as mentioned in Keras documentation [here](https://keras.io/applications/#classify-imagenet-classes-with-resnet50). Input to the model can be built both with 'channels_first' data format (channels, height, width) or 'channels_last' data format (height, width, channels).